# Mostrar si existe un fecha dentro de ese rango, en una consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy implementado un calendario, quisiera evitar insertar un evento si ya existe uno evitando que se crucen los eventos.

Ejemplo
Si hay un evento con fecha de inicio 2022-11-14 02:00:000 y final 2021-11-14 03:0:00.000.
Y no me deje insertar una fecha  2022-11-14 01:00:000 y final 2021-11-14 02:0:00.000.

```
SELECT *
FROM Reservas.centroempleo
WHERE sala = 'vestibulum' 
AND `start` <=  '2022-11-14 02:35:54.000'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá te sea útil utilizar [insert where not exists](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/subqueries-and-exists/)

Answer (score 0):

Yo me encontré que los Date Time no funcionan muy bien a la hora de hacer comparaciones (ya que están formados por un Date + Time) la solución es convertirlo en otro tipo de tiempo
ejemplo si lo quieres hacer por horas en el intervalo de un día:

```
SELECT *
FROM Reservas.centroempleo
WHERE sala = 'vestibulum' 
AND Date(`start`) =  '2022-11-14' AND Time(`start`) <='02:35:54.000'
```

Puedes usar TimeSpan si quieres comparar diferentes días:

```
 SELECT *
FROM Reservas.centroempleo
WHERE sala = 'vestibulum' 
AND TIMESTAMP(`start`) <=TIMESTAMP('2022-11-14','02:35:54.000')
```

Te dejo link para que puedas provar otros disponibles y puedas coger el que te vaya mejor. https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_timestamp.asp

Comment: ¿`TIMESPAN` o `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: TIMESTAMP me equivoqué al escribir a mano, ya que lo probé en VM

Comment: Vuelve a sobrar una P en la consulta :)

Comment: Si toda la razón XD

Answer (score 0):

Cree un ejemplo para la guía, pero básicamente es un stored procedure usando cláusula `BETWEEN` para la validación:

- Creo la tabla (obvia lo del `ID`):

```sql
create table ejemplo(id int, start datetime, end datetime); 
insert into ejemplo values(1, '2022-08-14 08:00:00', '2022-08-14 10:30:00')
```

- Se crea el stored procedure:

```sql
create procedure insertar_evento(in inicio datetime, in fin datetime)  
begin 

if not exists ( select 1 from ejemplo where start between inicio and fin 
                                            or end between inicio and fin )  then 

insert into ejemplo values(90, inicio, fin);
select 'procede! insertado!' as 'resultado';
else 
select 'no se puede insertar' as 'resultado';
end if; 

end
```

La explicación es que se insertan dos fechas, las que se quieren agregar, primero se valida si los campos `start` y `end` ya se encuentran entre esos rangos, de no ser así [`if not exists(...)`] entonces se procede con la inserción de data, de lo contrario arroja un mensaje de que no se puede.

- Ejemplos finales:

```sql
call insertar_evento('2022-08-14 06:00:00', '2022-08-14 07:45:00')

-- salida:
+---------------------+
| resultado           |
+---------------------+
| procede! insertado! |
+---------------------+

call insertar_evento('2022-08-14 08:00:00', '2022-08-14 10:45:00')

-- salida:
+----------------------+
| resultado            |
+----------------------+
| no se puede insertar |
+----------------------+
```

Obviamente faltan validaciones a nivel de rango de fechas, mejora visual para la salida final y demás, pero eso puedes hacerlo tú.

> [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9b73a67266d32433245d0dfdf9accdf) donde lo ejecuté.